# How to call object T from constructor copy T(const T&)?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, copy-constructor, const-reference

I have a copy constructor `T::T(const T&)`. The object has two properties, let's say `color` and `height`. This means I need to assign the color and the height from the object in argument to my object. Problem is I don't know how to call the argument because it is not named.

If the argument is named, let's say **t**, code looks like this:

```
T::T(const T& t) {
    color = t.color
    height = t.height
}
```

But in my case there's no **t** argument. What should I replace the question mark `?` with in the following code:

```
T::T(const T&) {
    color = ?.color
    height = ?.height
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: The real problem is the lack of a name for your parameter. What is stopping you from giving it a name? (You apparently can edit the function definition.)

Comment: That just makes no sense. Why would you not provide an argument name when you clearly need (and use) it?

Comment: Unlike many other languages (like for example Javascript) there's no universal "args" or similar variable. If you need to access an argument, you need to explicitly declare it as a formal argument in the *definition*.

Comment: Random guess: You saw the definition of a copy ctor being `T::T(const T&)` and now think it's forbidden to give the parameter a name? No need to worry, just name the parameter and use it as in your first example.

Comment: Putting together mine and dtell's comment, it seems you're confused about the difference between function *declarations* and *definitions*. in C++ you can omit argument variable names in declarations, and even definitions (implementations) if you want. But if you need to access an argument in the definition (implementation) of a function you *must* give that argument an explicit name.

Comment: Does that mean that declaration is T::T(const T&) and that I can implement that with T::T(const T& t)?

Comment: @MarcoAndréEcheverria Yes that's correct. In *declarations* of functions (class-members or not) you don't have to provide argument names).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! I've been trying to figure this out since a couple of hours now.

Comment: @MarcoAndréEcheverria • In my _declarations_ I only provide the dummy parameter names for documentation purposes.  Like `void DrawAt(int x, int y) const;` where the `x` and `y` help disambiguate their uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @some-programmer-dude mentioned, I was confused about the difference between function declarations and definitions.

My declaration was `T::T(const T&)` but that didn't stop me from defining an argument **t** in my definition `T::T(const T& t)`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible without naming the parameter.

When you omit the parameter name, you do it **because** you don't need it. If you **do** need it, don't omit it.